# Get visible cell's string

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, uilabel

As I scroll, I get visible cell's row number.

I'd like to get each row's string whenever I scroll.

*This is how I get row numbers -*

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{


CGRect visibleRect = (CGRect){.origin = self.tableView.contentOffset, .size = self.view.bounds.size};
CGPoint visiblePoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(visibleRect), CGRectGetMidY(visibleRect));
NSIndexPath *visibleIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:visiblePoint];

CGPoint minumunPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(visibleRect), CGRectGetMinY(visibleRect));

NSLog(@"minimum point : %i", (int)minumunPoint.y);
NSLog(@"visible Index Path.Row : %i, visible Point Y : %f", (int)visibleIndexPath.row, visiblePoint.y);

self.visibleIndex = (int)visibleIndexPath.row;
```

}

*This is how I'm setting strings in each cell -*

```
self.cell.objectID = [object objectId];
```

Comment: What about `NSLog(@"Labels: %@", [self.tableView visibleCells] valueForKeyPath:@"textLabel.text"]);`?

Answer (score 0):

It's not difficult as you already have indexPath

```
    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [self.tableView  cellForRowAtIndexPath:visibleIndexPath];
NSString *labelText = selectedCell.textLabel.text;
```

Comment: can u try selectedCell.objectID?

Comment: I tried that also but .objectID wouldn't show up... but it should I don't know why.

Comment: you are using custom cell. In place of UITableViewCell use your cell class

Comment: Ah, figured out why. Because I'm using custom cell class.

Comment: I managed to get the strings but as I knew it'd happen, same strings from same multiple rows return. IndexPath does not return unique row numbers I need row numbers.

Comment: I think you shuld consider @Jiri's answer

Answer (score 0):

You can pass visible cell's index and get label text of that particular cell. Here's some code

```
MessageTableViewCell *cell = (MessageTableViewCell*)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.visibleIndex];
    NSLog(@"label text %@",cell.textLabel.text);
```

If you have custom cell, change custom cell's name on `MessageTableViewCell`

Comment: cellForRowAtIndexPath:path returns section numbers I think. I get repeated strings from the same rows. cezhHCViPo, UiQTFCJaOA, cezhHCViPo, UiQTFCJaOA

Answer (score 0):

If you need all the visible cells use this:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    NSArray *paths = [tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];

    //get all visible rows
    for (NSIndexPath *path in paths) {
        NSLog(@"%ld", (long)path.row);

        //get this cell
        CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];
        //change value with scrolling
        cell.myLabel.text = @"aa";
    }
}
```

Comment: cellForRowAtIndexPath:path returns section numbers I think. I get repeated strings from the same rows. cezhHCViPo,
    UiQTFCJaOA,
    cezhHCViPo,
    UiQTFCJaOA